# What algorithm does the Matlab solver "Taylor" use to calculate the Taylor series of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The Matlab symbolic solver "Taylor" can calculate Taylor expansions for arguments like $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. I wonder what sort of algorithm is used for this computation.

If by any chance they use the long polynomial division then does the generated output represent the actual Taylor expansion of the quotient? Although the Taylor expansion of a product of two functions is a product of Taylor expansions of the two functions involved, the same is not true for the division. (I am not a mathematician, I am an engineer.)

Comment: Instead of division, $f(x)\cdot (g(x))^{-1}$ seems easier.

Comment: But getting higher order derivatives of (g(x))-1 can be a nightmare.  Is this what they do?

Answer (score 1):

Division works fine if you start from the larger terms, which are the ones of smallest degree.  As you say, multiplication works fine all the time, so we can take the numerator as $1$.  Then we have
$$\frac 1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\ldots$$
which is exactly what you get by doing polynomial long division starting at $1$.
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \ \  \underline{1-x+x^2}\\
1+x|1\\
\quad\quad\quad\ \ \ \ \ \underline {1+x}\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \ -x\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \underline {-x-x^2}\\
\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x^2$$
forgive my ASCII approach to formatting a long division problem in MathJax

Comment: Yes, but why in your proof/example? you divide by 1+x. Is this general enough?